# Redirect in JavaScript without losing the form post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a contact form that submits data once multiple checks have been performed. My problem is that the page redirects before the submit can be submitted, is there a way to wait for a response from the server.

```
    if ( !form_error ) {    
        $form.submit();
    }
    message += '</ul>';
    if ( message != '<ul></ul>' )
    {
        if($form_redirect.length)
        {
            window.location.href = $form_redirect;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Wait how? If you have a regular form submit, the server does respond, with the page you're redirecting to ?

Comment: you should redirect from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to try and redirect the user with the response from the server. Your form will submit to the server, and the server will send up the new page.

Comment: I was planning on doing it within php, but just to further my knowledge and look at all possibilities i have seen ways of doing it in Javascript. For example submitting the action of the form with values in an array with JSON list. this is contained inside a '$contact.load()' method with a response method.

Comment: You may want to use an AJAX request then. I'm not sure that you can submit the form and remain on your current page without doing so.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help :) , its just so i can expand my learning and use a different approach.